# PostgreSQL Addition in Primary Key in Create Table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, key

i'm facing a problem with a primary key in PostgreSQL, my plan was to make an addition of two  values and set this to one primary key, how could this be realized (first try below):

```
/* Tabelle fuer die Test*/  
create table Test(
var_a integer,
var_b integer,
var_key integer,
var_key = var_a + var_b,
primarykey(var_key),
);
```

if i call this with a foreign key then  it should be one value:

```
foreign key (var_key_f) references Test(var_key),
```

EDIT: I know th option of two multiple primary keys entries but i want to have only one primary key, so that i not have to reference over two vars again. I need to have both variables generated to one primary key.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having a primary key with two columns (note: it's not "*multiple primary keys*" it's still a *single* primary key - just with multiple columns). But your question does not make any sense. Which row should the value 42 reference? The row with a=1 and b=41 or the row with a=2 and b=40 or the row with a=3 and b=39 or ....

Comment: i think it should be an additon of the two elements.. as example a=1 b=41 key=42

Comment: So you don't want to store `(20,22)` in the table if `(1,41)` is already present? Then why not store the sum right away.

Comment: true.. maybe it would be better to concat them in a  way i don't know?

Comment: No, that won't be better. Would `'1234'` then refer to `(12,34)` or `(1,234)` or (123,4)? Create a two-column primary (and foreign) key and be done with it. I really don't understand why you don't want to do that. If your primary key consists of two columns so be it.

Comment: Strange requirements. There are a few ways to implement this, most of them will need triggers to maintain the `var_key=var_a + var_b` equality. Maybe a functional index solution would not need any triggers.

Comment: Do you actually want all three _columns_ {var_a,var_b,var_key} to be present in the table, or do you only need the _expression_ `var_a+var_b` to be unique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this can be accomplished without triggers: (pg-9.3):

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE test
        ( var_key INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , var_a INTEGER NOT NULL
        , var_b INTEGER NOT NULL
        , var_key_f INTEGER REFERENCES test(var_key)
        , CONSTRAINT the_sum CHECK (var_a+var_b = var_key)
        );

INSERT INTO test(var_key, var_a, var_b) VALUES(42, 21, 21); -- Ok
INSERT INTO test(var_key, var_a, var_b) VALUES(666, 660, 6); -- Ok

INSERT INTO test(var_key, var_a, var_b) VALUES(34, 21, 11); -- bad sum
INSERT INTO test(var_key, var_a, var_b) VALUES(666, 600, 66); -- duplicate sum

INSERT INTO test(var_key, var_a, var_b, var_key_f) VALUES(14, 6, 8, 42); -- Ok
INSERT INTO test(var_key, var_a, var_b, var_key_f) VALUES(13, 5, 8, 43); -- Bad FK
```

Result:

```
NOTICE:  drop cascades to table tmp.test
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  new row for relation "test" violates check constraint "the_sum"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (34, 21, 11, null).
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (var_key)=(666) already exists.
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  insert or update on table "test" violates foreign key constraint "test_var_key_f_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (var_key_f)=(43) is not present in table "test".
```

Comment: Defining the "primary key" is not the problem, but Stefan wants to declare a *foreign* key referencing that calculated value.

Comment: Then just add the foreign key; it is only an extra constraint ?

Comment: But Stefan wants to define the primary key on the **sum** of the two values not on the two columns.

Comment: Totally unclear what the OP wants. He does define to be var_key as a column, not as an expression, so I modelled it as a column with an additonal constraint. (of course, one of the var_{a,b,key} will be redundant, but that is a different matter, IMO. Maintaining the sum automatically would need a trigger, plus a choice of what to update in case of conflicts)

Comment: kk thx.. but not totally unclear ;) otherwise a_horse_with_no_name wouldn't have understanding.